# How to pass value from javascript to controller function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm completely new into this angular js. I have javascript file by using I can able to get some data. I want to process that data in controller function. But I can't able to do this. I'm already imported controller file also as below,

external.js --location /src/js/test.js

```
import MainController from '../../src/app/result/Maincontroller'
....
....
....

var foo = "testdata"
```

MainController.js

```
Import External from ../../src/js/test.js
angular.module('WebApp').controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl)
function ResultCtrl ($scope) { 
        $scope.testfunc = function(data) {
        console.log(data)
        }
    }
```

How to pass this foo value to $scope.testfunc(). Please tell me how do I call this controller function from external javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared foo as a global variable and should be accessible in your controller by its name (foo). The only thing you need to worry about is that you need to have the reference of the file containing global variable in your view (html file) and that controller's js file is inicluded after the js file containing the variable foo.

Although this will do the job for you but it is not the recommended approach specially in angularjs. You should use Angularjs services for exposing data to controllers.

Answer (score 0):

To access a variable `foo` declared globally, you can use `$window.foo`. You might need to add the dependency to $window:

```
angular.module('WebApp').controller('MainController', ['$window', $window) {
  // Here you can access your global variable as
  console.log('FOO is', $window.foo);
}]);
```

To call a controller method, you need to bind an action to a DOM element that is managed by your Angular app.
You should find in your code something like this:

```
<div ng-app="WebApp" ng-controller="MainController">
  <!-- Everything in here which is ng-something can be managed by Angular -->
  <button ng-click="bar()">This button can call the bar() function</button>
</div>
```

In the future, start to bind your data with [Angular services](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_services.asp) which are the common best practices to load data in the scope of controllers.